# How to show google map navigation url in webview android

Tags: android, google-maps

I need the following code to load in webview.

```
   final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
   Uri.parse(
            "http://maps.google.com/maps?" +
            "saddr=43.0054446,-87.9678884" +
            "&daddr=42.9257104,-88.0508355"));

   intent.setClassName(
          "com.google.android.apps.maps",
          "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");

  startActivity(intent);
```

How do I do this?

Comment: That will not open an url in a WebView. If it would work then the user could choose one of the installed apps/browsers.

Answer (score 12):

This will load the URL to your webview:

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr=43.0054446,-87.9678884" + "&daddr=42.9257104,-88.0508355");
```

**Edit:**

Here are some screenshots using the code above.  Google Map Navigation in a web view:

[image: Directions]

[image: Map]

**Edit:**

Activity:

```
package com.example.webview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr=43.0054446,-87.9678884" + "&daddr=42.9257104,-88.0508355");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.webview.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.webview"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.webview.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: @Kirthiga Did you add the following permission to the manifest: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: yes i have added the internet permission.Your Screenshots looks like loading in a browser.I need to load the navigation url in webview.

Comment: @Kirthiga This is not loading in a browser.  This is loaded in a webview in my activity.

Comment: @todd : Perfect answer for what I was looking for. Thanks a lot todd :-)

Comment: @todd Does this option give you the possibility to get the location of the user and show the location on the map?