# android - google map v3 load markers from sql

Tags: android, web-services, google-maps-api-3, localhost

I create a google map web page where the lat and lon is loaded from local host mysql and save as .txt and will be load and mark to the google map web page and It work, So is it possible to convert it as an android webview ? or there is an much easier way.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to using webView in Android , try this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487889/how-to-show-google-map-navigation-url-in-webview-android):

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//just replace the actual latlong values with your variables from SQL
webview.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr=43.0054446,-87.9678884" + "&daddr=42.9257104,-88.0508355");
```

There's also a [Using PHP/MySQL with Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3) guide from Google docs where you store latlng values in SQL and load the markers to the map with the help of PHP.

This [video demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3j0AwmcBkyQ) might help in the implementation.